# counting values using count function

Tags: python, django

i have the following template namely **index.html**.I am working in django framework.Now i have shown the value where the all speed of a car is more than 30km.I just posted here the part of the associated code which output the value,that is,the code is

```
{% for v in values %}
      {% if v.speed > 30 %}
        {{v.speed}}
      {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

now i just want to count the v.speed values,how can i do that using python or django count function.You can edit my code in that section.

Thank You.

Answer (score 1):

If `values` is a Django QuerySet you can just use `.count()`

```
{% for v in values %}
  {% if v.speed > 30 %}
    {{v.speed}}
  {% endif %}
{% endfor %}

{{values.count}}
```

You can also use `{{values|length}}`

Answer (score 1):

Variable assignment is not allowed in django. So, your only alternative is do the counting in python itself & pass the corresponding data to the template.

Thus, you should do the following in python

```
speedy_values = [v for v in values if v.speed > 30]
```

And then, pass the speedy_values to your template

```
{% for v in speedy_values %}
      {{v.speed}}
{% endfor %}
{{ v|length }} number of cars have speed greater than 30.
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, since your `QuerySet` has been already evaluated, using the `length` filter would save you an additional query:

```
{% for v in values %}
  {% if v.speed > 30 %}
    {{v.speed}}
  {% endif %}
{% endfor %}

{{values|length}}
```

[Documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#length).